# Deriving the stochastic process for a dividend-yielding stock (under Black-Scholes assumptions)

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-processes, itos-lemma, dividends

In order to derive the Black-Scholes equation for a stock $S(t)$ yielding dividends at the continuous rate $d$
$$
S(t) = S_0 e^{(\mu - d - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})t + \sigma \sqrt{t} N(0,1)} \text{,}
$$ M. Joshi in *The concepts and practice of mathematical finance* starts from the stochastic process for a delivery contract $X(t) = e^{-d (T - t)} S(t)$, equation (5.76):

$$
dX_t = (\mu + d) X_t dt + \sigma X_t dW_t \qquad \qquad (1)
$$

He defines a delivery contract $X_t$ as a contract where you pay for stock $S_t$ today, but it gets delivered to you at time $T$. He writes that for a non-dividend paying stock, $X_t$ at time $T$ has the same value of $S_t$ as both end up with you holding one $S_t$. Then he makes the case of a dividend paying stock (included in text snapshot below): at time $T$ you will have $e^{d(T−t)}S_t$ if you held the stock, while only $S_t$ if you held a delivery contract, so the latter's value at $T$ must be $X_t=e^{−d(T−t)}S_t$.

However equation (5.76), renamed (1) above is thrown there as is and not motivated by any derivation.
I have tried deriving it from the $X_t$ and $S_t$ processes listed above, using the chain rule ($=$ Ito's lemma here because $\dfrac{\partial^2 X_t}{\partial S^2} = 0$):

$$
\begin{align}
dX_t(S_t, t) & =\\ &= \frac{\partial X_t}{\partial S_t} dS_t + \left[ \frac{\partial X_t}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial X_t}{\partial S_t} \frac{\partial S_t}{\partial t} \right] dt \\
&= e^{-d(T - t)} \left[ ( \mu - d) S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t \right] + \left[ e^{-d (T - t)} S_t d + e^{-d (T - t)} S_t  \left(\mu - d - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right)\right] dt \\
&= X_t \left[ \left( 2 \mu - d - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right) dt + \sigma dW_t \right] \qquad \qquad (2)
\end{align}
$$

where I have used $dS_t = (\mu - d) S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t$.

Equations (1) and (2) differ, in that they have different deterministic components.

Can anyone enlighten me as where errors/incongruities are in the above?

Below, the passage from the book included as snapshot.

[image: Directly from the book]

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a  comment. I'd  offer even a third derivation:
$$
\begin{align}
dS/S&=(\mu-d)dt+\sigma dW\\
X&\equiv e^{-d(T-t)}S_t\\
\Rightarrow dX&=\frac{\partial X}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial X}{\partial S }dS\\
&=de^{-d(T-t)}S_tdt+e^{-d(T-t)}dS\\
&=dX_tdt+e^{-d(T-t)}S\left[(\mu-d)dt+\sigma dW\right]\\
&=dX_tdt+X_t(\mu-d)dt+X_t\sigma dW\\
&=X_t\mu dt+X_t\sigma dW\\
&=X_t(\mu dt+\sigma dW)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I'd agree with you, but on the book it is stated the derivation should lead to $d X_t = (\mu + d) X_t dt + \sigma X_t dW_t$ (eq 5.76, or eq.1 in my question above).

Comment: @Giogre : your equation $$
S(t) = S_0 e^{(\mu - d - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})(T - t) + \sigma \sqrt{T - t} N(0,1)} \text{,}
$$ looks wrong. The stock has no maturity $T$. The correct solution of the SDE for $S$ is $$
S(t) = S_0 e^{(\mu - d - \frac{\sigma^2}{2})\color{red}{t} + \sigma \color{red}{W_t}}.
$$

Comment: @KurtG. question edited to include your correction

Comment: With Kermittfrog's answer I don't  see a problem. Do you ?

Comment: @KurtG. I have included a snapshot of the 'incriminated' excerpt from the book, so you can see with your own eyes

Comment: We need more context.  What is it that Joshi tries to achieve ? 1. Define precisely why the investor who buys one stock at time $t$ holds $\color{red}{e^{d(T-t)}}$ stocks at time $T$. How exactly does that work, in particular what happens with the dividends? 2. What exactly is the delivery contract ? What happens with the dividends ?

Comment: @KurtG. he defines a delivery contract $X$ as a contract where you pay for the stock $S$ today, but it gets delivered to you at time T. He says that for a non-dividend paying stock, $X$ at time T has the same value of $S$ as both end up with you holding one $S$. Then he makes the case of a dividend paying stock, and this is in the excerpt: at time $T$ you will have $e^{d(T-t)} S$ if you held the stock, while only $S$ if you held a delivery contract, so the latter's value at $T$ must be $X= e^{-d(T-t)}S$.